ModuleNotFoundError when running Python application on Windows nanoserver container
I am trying to slim down docker image so I changed windowsservercore to nanoserver
There is no official python image on nanoserver so I wanted to build such myself. Please find the dockerfile below
FROM python:3.11.7-windowsservercore-1809 as python_image

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:nanoserver-1809
USER ContainerAdministrator
SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Copying python from python image
COPY --from=python_image C:\\Python C:\\Python

# Updating PATH env variable
RUN $env:PATH = 'C:\Python;C:\Python\Scripts;{0}' -f $env:PATH ; \
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

# Just checking the python and pip versions
RUN python --version && \
    pip --version 

RUN pip install python-pptx
CMD  ["python", "-c", "import pptx"]

But when I run the container I see the following error
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

Obviously, the Image package is installed and what is crucial is that the error doesn't occur when I use mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809 image as a base image.
What is missing in my nanoserver python image?
